# Python pandas lookup values based on timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like something this:

```
 product month
 apple  Jan-18
 pear   Jan-18
 banana Jan-18
 apple  Jan-18
 pear   Feb-18
 apple  Feb-18
 banana Feb-18
```

I have created my own reference table that looks like this:

```
id product     start       end    weight
1  apple    01/01/2011  31/01/2018 heavy
1  apple    01/02/2018  31/12/2020 small
2  banana   01/01/2015  31/01/2018 heavy
2  banana   01/02/2018  31/12/2020 small
3  pear     01/01/2016  31/12/2020 heavy
```

The reference table always starts with the first and last days of the month. The 'weight' field is slowly changing over time. For example, apple and banana have changed over time. The date 31/12/2020 means this is currently the active dimension for the product.

I need to merge the 'weight' in the reference table with my DataFrame on product depending on the timestamp. I need to get this:

```
 product month weight
 apple  Jan-18 heavy
 pear   Jan-18 heavy
 banana Jan-18 heavy
 apple  Jan-18 heavy
 pear   Feb-18 heavy
 apple  Feb-18 small
 banana Feb-18 small
```

My difficulty is that I don't know where to start. The date fields in my DataFrame and reference table are datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column in ref_df having similar structure as month column of ref_df

Merge the two dataframes on the newly created column

```
def month_conversion(x):
    month_list = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','June','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
    return month_list[int(x.month)-1] 

ref_df['year'] = ref_df['start'].head().map(lambda x: str(x.year)[-2:])

ref_df['month'] = ref_df.loc[0:5,'start'].map(month_conversion)

ref_df['common_key'] = ref_df['month'] +'-' +ref_df['year']
my_df['month'] = my_df['month'].astype(str)
final_df = ref_df.merge(my_df,left_on=['common_key','product'],right_index=['month','product'],suffixes=('_merge',''))
```

Comment: I am getting the following: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float for return month_list[x.month-1]

Comment: my bad it means x.month is a float. Just do month_list[int(x.month)-1]